# Swap two fragment simultaneously

Tags: android

In my application i have one activity and i am adding two fragments at run time.I need to swap these two fragment simultaneously. Fragment 1 consist a button and i want when i click that button fragment 1 moves to right side of the screen and other fragment to the left side of the activity.

In the onClick method of the button i tried something like this

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         Fragment newFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pageA);
         ft.remove(newFragment);
         Fragment newFragmentB = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pageB);
         ft.remove(newFragmentB);
         ft.add(R.id.pageB, newFragment);
         ft.add(R.id.pageA, newFragmentB);
         ft.addToBackStack(null);
         ft.commit();
     }
```

But i am getting the following error

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment PageA{40653da0   #0 id=0x7f060001}: was 2131099649 now 2131099650
```

I want something like this when i click the button on Page A then Position of Page A and PageB should swap with each other.

[image: UI of the fragment]

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue ( [IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906254/illegalstateexception-cant-change-container-id-of-fragment) ) and i solved by swapping the containers instead of the fragments... Nonetheless i still have no clue as to whether it's possibile to swap directly fragments. As I wrote in the aforementioned post, it seems to work only on ics!

Comment: i.e. what i also found it is not working on honeycomb. I never tried it on ICS. then it might be an Android issue

Comment: It works on ICS as long as you remove and add a frag in two separate transactions (have a look at the link above to see how it's done)

Answer (score 0):

I posted a solution to this problem to a similar question. My approach is to re-create the fragment, but keeping the state by saving it first and re-applying it to the new instance.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14951987/599614.