# Android multi level Master-Detail flow with two pane mode

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, master-detail

I am currently playing around with one and two pane mode in Android, using `Fragment`s. Basically I am having some kind of Master/Detail flow, where every Detail is again a Master for other Details.
For example we have a Master `Clients` with the Detail `Client`. Each `Client` is  again some kind of Master with a list of `Orders`. The `Orders` then have the Detail `Order`. Each `Order` has a list of `Articles` with the Detail `Article` and so on.
So I would like to have a two pane layout, with the Master on the left and the Detail on the right. As every Detail is a Master to, when going to it's Details i would like to shift the whole `Layout` to the left. So the "old" Master falls out of the `Layout` on the left and the new List/Detail enters the `Layout` from the right.

It should basically look something like this:

[image: Clients/Client]

On the left I have the `Clients` and on the right I have the detail of the selected client `John`.
Now if I click on the `Orders...` in the detail, I want to move in the `Orders` list from right, pushing the `Clients` master and the detail to the left.
The result should look something like this:

[image: Client/Orders]

So basicly the `Clients` master moved out of the `Layout`, the `Client` detail is now on the left and the `Orders` master is on the right.
Clicking on one of the `Orders` should again, move the detail of that `Order` in from the right and push the `Client` master out on the left.
The result:

[image: Orders/Order]

To create the transition I did the following:

1. Create a horizontal `LinearLayout` with 3 `FrameLayout` children.
2. Set the `layout_weight` of the 1st and 2nd `FrameLayout` to 1.0f and the one of the 3rd to 0.0f.
3. Create an `Animation` for the `layout_weight` of the 1st and 3rd `FrameLayout`, turning the 1st from 1.0 to 0.0 and the 3rd from 0.0 to 1.0
4. Wait until the `Animation` finishes
5. Replace the `Fragment` from the 1st `FrameLayout` with the one from the 2nd and move the `Fragment` from the 3rd `FrameLayout` into the 2nd.
6. Reset the `layout_weight`.

This works perfectly, if you [remember to remove](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21328878/3182091) the `Fragment` from one container before adding it to the other.
The problem I am having with this solution is, when i want to go back.
As a user I would expect, that the previous master comes in from the left and pushes the current detail out on the right (the reverse animation).
I guess it would be the best to use the Fragment-Backstack, but i just can't figure out how to do it.
So how should I manage the "going back"? Or is there a better solution for this kind of "multi-level master-detail flow"?

Comment: Did you try with SligingPaneLayout?

Comment: Never heard of it, I am going to check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @WindRider It seems like the `SlidingPaneLayout` does only support 2 children. But in my case 3 Fragments could be seen at a time: The `master`, which is sliding out on the left, the `detail`, which becomes the new master and the new `detail`, sliding in from the right. I can't see how to solve this, using the `SlidingPaneLayout`

Comment: Last year I've tried to implement totally the same task but gave up. Too many problems making the code hard to maintain. Do you know how to enable the chat here?

Comment: @WindRider Thats the problem I have with my solution. It seems pretty hard to maintain the backstack, as multiple `FragmentTransaction`s are neccessary... Btw. the chat is [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Cool, lets use it: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132426/android-master-detail-layout

Comment: @WindRider I did not have time to join the chat until now... Sorry for that!