# Can't change container ID of fragment Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am working on the development of an Android App. In an Activity there will be two tab. Each of the tabs are individual fragments. I am retrieving some JSON data from the server in Async task and setting those data into the TextView of the Fragment Layout.

So far I understand I have to replace the fragment in the main activity to achieve this. I am getting following error while running the app.

```js
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment MutualFunds{ed3a1c0 #0 id=0x7f080096}: was 2131230870 now 2131230812
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:422)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:444)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:434)
        at com.testappl.ivest.ICLProducts.changefrag(ICLProducts.java:234)
        at com.testappl.ivest.ICLProducts$JsonTask.onPostExecute(ICLProducts.java:207)
        at com.testappl.ivest.ICLProducts$JsonTask.onPostExecute(ICLProducts.java:101)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
```

Here is my Fragment Activity class:

```js
package com.testappl.ivest;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.testappl.ivest.model.FundMaster;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MutualFunds.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link MutualFunds#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class MutualFunds extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM3 = "param3";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM4 = "param4";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private String mParam3;
    private String mParam4;
    private static View view;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    TextView mBFLabel;
    TextView mBFDefintion;
    TextView mBFCurrentNAV;
    TextView mBFCurrentReturn;

    TextView mGFLabel;
    TextView mGFDefinition;
    TextView mGFCurrentNAV;
    TextView mGFCurrentReturn;


    public MutualFunds() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MutualFunds.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MutualFunds newInstance(String param1, String param2,String param3,String param4) {
        MutualFunds fragment = new MutualFunds();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM3, param3);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM4, param4);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            mParam3=getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM3);
            mParam4=getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM4);
        }

        if(savedInstanceState==null){
            Fragment MutualFundFragment=new Fragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                    add(R.id.fragment_mutual_funds,MutualFundFragment,
                            "mutual_fund_tag").commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mutual_funds, container, false);
        mBFLabel=view.findViewById(R.id.fund_name_bf);
        mBFDefintion=view.findViewById(R.id.fund_definition_bf);
        mBFCurrentNAV=view.findViewById(R.id.current_nav_bf);
        mBFCurrentReturn=view.findViewById(R.id.current_return_bf);

        mBFLabel.setText(mParam1);
        mBFDefintion.setText(mParam2);

        mGFLabel=view.findViewById(R.id.fund_name_gf);
        mGFDefinition=view.findViewById(R.id.fund_definition_gf);
        mGFCurrentNAV=view.findViewById(R.id.current_nav_gf);
        mGFCurrentReturn=view.findViewById(R.id.current_return_gf);

        mGFLabel.setText(mParam3);
        mGFDefinition.setText(mParam4);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mutual_funds, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    //Change the texts of Balanced Fund
    public  void changeBFTexts(FundMaster fm){


        mBFLabel.setText(fm.getFundName());
        mBFDefintion.setText(fm.getFundDefinition());


    }

    //Change the texts of Growth Fund
    public  void changeGFTexts(FundMaster fm){

        mGFLabel.setText(fm.getFundName());
        mGFDefinition.setText(fm.getFundDefinition());
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Here is my Fragment Layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MutualFunds"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_mutual_funds">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fund_name_bf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:text="@string/mutualfundfrag_iclbf_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fund_definition_bf"
            android:layout_width="319dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/mutualfundfrag_iclbf_definition"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fund_name_bf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_nav_bf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/mutualfundfrag_iclbf_current_nav"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fund_definition_bf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_return_bf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/mutualfundfrag_iclbf_current_return"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/current_nav_bf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fund_performance_bf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/mutualfundfrag_iclbf_fund_performance"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/current_return_bf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fund_name_gf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:text="@string/mutualfundfrag_bcbiclgf_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fund_performance_bf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fund_definition_gf"
            android:layout_width="315dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/mutualfundfrag_bcbiclgf_definition"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fund_name_gf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_nav_gf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/mutualfundfrag_iclbf_current_nav"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fund_definition_gf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_return_gf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/mutualfundfrag_iclbf_current_return"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/current_nav_gf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fund_performance_gf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/mutualfundfrag_iclbf_fund_performance"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/current_return_gf" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the parent activity where the async task is there and the fragment is going to replaced:

```js
super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pd.isShowing()){
                pd.dismiss();
            }
            try {

                JSONArray resultJsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                ArrayList<FundMaster> fundsData=new ArrayList<FundMaster>();

                for(int i=0;i<resultJsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject= (JSONObject) resultJsonArray.get(i);
                    fundsData.add(new FundMaster(Integer.valueOf(jsonObject.get("f_id").toString()),
                            Integer.valueOf(jsonObject.get("fund_id").toString()),
                            jsonObject.get("fund_name").toString(),
                            jsonObject.get("fund_definition").toString(),
                            jsonObject.get("fund_date").toString()));
                }
                for(FundMaster fm:fundsData){
                    Log.d("Fund Name",fm.getFundName());
                    Log.d("Fund Launch Date",fm.getFundLaunchDate());
                    //MutualFunds mf=new MutualFunds();


                    //View view=fragment.getView();
                    if(mutualFundFragment!=null) {
                        if (fm.getFundId() == 1) {
                            mutualFundFragment.changeBFTexts(fm);
                        } else if (fm.getFundId() == 2) {
                            mutualFundFragment.changeGFTexts(fm);
                        }
                    } else{
                        Log.e("Message Error","Error");
                    }

                    changefrag(mutualFundFragment);
                }



            } catch (JSONException e){
                Log.e("JSON Error","JSON problem");
            }






        }
    }

   public void changefrag(android.support.v4.app.Fragment frag) {


        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();


        if (!manager.beginTransaction().isEmpty()) {
            manager.beginTransaction().detach(frag);
        }
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_mutual_funds, frag).commit();
       

    }
```

As far I understand, Static Fragment cannot be replaced. Can anyone suggest me what should I do in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906254/illegalstateexception-cant-change-container-id-of-fragment

Comment: I saw that question. But the problem is, no answer is stated as correct answer. And I tried to follow the most upvoted solution and it did not work out.