# Switching between Fragments in a single Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to create an `Activity` which shows a sort of menu a user can go through. By clicking an item, a new screen is shown, allowing the user more options (wizard-like).

I wanted to implement this using `Fragment`s, but it's not working for me.
Right now I have:

`main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_fragmentcontainer" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainmenufragment"
        android:name="com.myapp.MainMenuFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondmenufragment"
        android:name="com.myapp.SecondMenuFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`MainMenuFragment` with an `OnClickListener`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainmenu, container, false);

    setupButton(view);
    return view;
}

/* Button setup code omitted */

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    SherlockFragment secondRunMenuFragment = (SherlockFragment) getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.secondmenufragment);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, secondMenuFragment); //also crashes with R.id.main_fragmentcontainer
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Now when I press the button, the application crashes with this logcat:

> 06-27 01:45:26.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8747): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment SecondMenuFragment{405e2a70 #1 id=0x7f060029}: was 2131099689 now 2131099687
>   06-27 01:45:26.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8747):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(Unknown Source)
>   06-27 01:45:26.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8747):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(Unknown Source)
>   06-27 01:45:26.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8747):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(Unknown Source)
>   06-27 01:45:26.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8747):   at com.myapp.MainMenuFragment$MyButtonOnClickListener.onClick(MainMenuFragment.java:52)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [There's a similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092048/swap-two-fragment-simultaneously)

Comment: If you are trying to create a wizard, what is the second `<fragment>` for?

Comment: I've seen those links indeed, but I don't know how to apply them in my case.

Comment: @CommonsWare The first `Fragment` shows the first menu with buttons `1`, `2` and `3`. The second `Fragment` shows a second menu with buttons `1.1`, `1.2` and `1.3`. The plan is to add a third `Fragment` with buttons `2.1`, `2.2` and `2.3`. Or am I approaching this all wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Personally, I would not have any `<fragment>` elements.

Step #1: Populate your activity layout with a `<FrameLayout>` for the variable piece of the wizard, plus your various buttons.

Step #2: In `onCreate()` of the activity, run a `FragmentTransaction` to load the first wizard page into the `FrameLayout`.

Step #3: On the "next" click, run a `FragmentTransaction` to replace the contents of the `FrameLayout` with the next page of the wizard.

Step #4: Add in the appropriate smarts for disabling the buttons when they are unusable (e.g., back on the first wizard page).

Also, you will want to think about how the BACK button should work in conjunction with any on-screen "back" button in the wizard. If you want them to both behave identically, you will need to add each transaction to the back stack and pop stuff off the back stack when you handle the "back" button.

Someday, if nobody beats me to it, I'll try to create a wizard-by-way-of-fragments example, or perhaps a reusable component.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you right, but I got it working somehow. I've put an empty `<FrameLayout>` in my activity layout file. Then, in `onCreate()` of the activity, I called `FragmentTransaction.add()` to add `new MainMenuFragment()` to `R.id.main_fragmentcontainer`, the id of the `<FrameLayout>`. In the `MainMenuFragment` `onClick()` I create a `new SecondMenuFragment()`, and add it the same way, again to `R.id.main_fragmentcontainer`. That at least works. I'm especially confused in step 1 _plus your various buttons_. What do you mean by  that? And couldn't I just use `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @Niek: "What do you mean by that?" -- usually a wizard interface has "previous" (or "back") and "next" buttons. There is no reason to put those in the fragments, as they stay the same throughout all wizard steps, so I would presume you would put them directly in the activity. "And couldn't I just use LinearLayout?" -- for what?

Comment: Oh those buttons, I thought you meant my menu buttons. And you suggested a FrameLayout in step 1, but I guess that has to do with the overlay of the "next" and "previous" buttons. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Niek: The `FrameLayout` was the "slot" in which to put the fragments. `FrameLayout` is often used for this, as it's a pretty cheap container processing-wise, I suppose. So long as it behaves as you wish, any `ViewGroup` should technically work.

Answer (score 18):

I create this main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   tools:context="com.example.fragmentsexample.MainActivity" >

   <FrameLayout 
      android:id="@+id/contentFragment"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I replenished in the FrameActivity with:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  Fragment fragment = new Dashboard();
  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment);
  transaction.commit();
  ...
}
```

And I repleace on onClick Method with the same code, changing Fragment (Dashboard for Events):

```
@Override
public void onClick.... {
  ...
  Fragment fragment = new Events();
  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment); //Container -> R.id.contentFragment
  transaction.commit();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [Android-WizardPager](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager) by Roman Nurik.

Key features:

- Branching, or the ability for wizard steps to influence the
  availability of later steps
- Allowing the user to review before committing
- Allowing the user freeform navigation between wizard steps
- Support for required and optional steps
- Support for step classes (technically, each step is an instance of a Java class, so you can have multiple instances within the wizard)

More info [here.](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/6cVymZvn3f4)